# Redhat 7.1 kernel process stack size from 8K to 16KB

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, redhat

Reading the release note of `Redhat 7.1`, I read this:

```
Process Stack Size Increased from 8KB to 16KB
Since Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.1, the kernel process stack size has been increased from 8KB to 16KB to help large processes that use stack space.
```

I know the kernel process stack are resident memory and the allocation is made when processes are created and that memory needs to be contiguous, In `x86_64` with page size of 4096 bytes, the kernel will need to find 4 pages intend of 2 pages for the process stack.

This feature can be a problem when the kernel memory is fragmented?
With one process kernel stack size, will be more easier to have a problem with process creation when the memory will be fragmented?

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear and not really programming related.

Comment: is about linux kernel process stack

Comment: Alright. I will answer your question. Then you will see why your question has a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will add something to my questions.

Comment: I don't see how this is programming related. It's also not a problem. The pages that make up the kernel stack don't need to be contiguous in physical RAM. They need to be contiguous in the virtual address space, but the 64-bit kernel virtual address space is huge, 128 TB, so fragmentation is never an issue.

Comment: @RossRidge kernel process stack is logical address 1:1 mapping, I not sure fragmentation is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel often needs to allocate a set of one or more pages which are physically contiguous. This may be necessary while allocating buffers (required by drivers for data transfers such as DMA) or when creating a process stack.

Typically, to meet such requirements, kernel attempts to avoid fragmentation by allocating pages which are physically contiguous and additionally freed pages are merged/grouped into larger physically contiguous group of pages (if available). This is handled by the memory management sub-system and the buddy allocator. Now when your stack (`8k` or `16k` in RHEL7) is created when the program has starts executing.

If kernel is unable to obtain or allocate a the requested set of physically contiguous pages (either 2 for 8k stack or 4 for 16k stack assuming 4k page size), then this could potentially lead to `page allocation failures, order:2`. (i.e 2^2=4 pages * 4K). The order depends on the size of your physically contiguous pages requested. We can observe the `/proc/buddyinfo` file during the time when page allocation failures occur, it could show signs of physically memory being fragmented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

When memory is fragmented finding stack space can be a problem.

Comment: Does the kernel process stack have to reside in contiguous physical memory?